# "track by" not working when returning new object in ng-controller function used in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone explain why this simple demo code always have the error:
"[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

http://jsfiddle.net/bigbearzhu/Sx3Qq/

There is one scope function returning new object with same data every time:

```
$scope.items = function() {
    return [
        { id: 1 }
    ];
};
```

The track by item.id seems not working to stop the error.

Can't figure out how to get rid of the error. Drove me crazy for hours!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate

Comment: @bradciven, thanks. It is similar, but may not be the same issue.