# Hide table rows in angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have a table, I am already given it CSS using ng-class if they satisfy a condition. Now I want to show only those rows who satisfy the same condition on a  button click. I have wrote a controller which checks if the data received is within 24 hours are not and marks the data cell. Until this it's working.Now I need to add a button and show only the row which has this td marked as not received in time.

```
<tbody>

       <tr ng-repeat ="data in log">
            <td>{{data.UniqueId}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
            <td ng-class ="{'data-notreceived' : dataNotReceived('data.receivedTime')}">{{data.receivedTime
        }}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Show us your code. Your question as it is right now is vary vague, what is the condition?

Comment: @yvesmancera edited it.

Comment: where are your `{{curly braces}}` ?!

Comment: @Priya. Welcome to `SO`. Will you please share your controller code as well ?

Comment: @all Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work. Basically, clicking the button will toggle between showing all or only the items marked as 'data not received'.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat ="data in log" ng-show="showAll || dataNotReceived(data.receivedTime)">
    <td>{{data.UniqueId}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
    <td ng-class ="{'data-notreceived' : dataNotReceived('data.receivedTime')}">{{data.receivedTime}}
  </tr>
</tbody>

// in controller
$scope.showAll = true;

$scope.onButtonClick = function() {
  $scope.showAll = !$scope.showAll;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GPicazo, but i am facing this issue error: [$rootscope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.

Comment: Thanks for this , but now i am stuck with another button where I have to show rows which do not satisfy the condition. @GPicazo

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided in question what I can say is: Use ng-show to show rows based on your condition.

```
    <tr ng-show ="your_condition">
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the same but facing angular issue error: [$rootscope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Comment: @Priya I hope this addresses similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an **ng-if** rather than ng-show. See the differences [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/).

Really depends on how often the hide/show toggle needs to happen.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in log" ng-if="showLast24Hrs(data.ReceivedTime)">
          <td>{{data.UniqueId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.ReceivedTime}}</td>
      </tbody>
```

and then in the controller,

```
$scope.showLast24Hrs = function(receivedTime){
    if($scope.isLast24Hours) {
      return receivedTime < 200;  // Write your less than 24 hours check here
    }
    return true;
  }
```

I wrote this [demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/vinkamat/pen/LpEBBE). Hope that helps.