# location.reload() giving error

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `location.reload()` / `$window.location.reload()` function to reload my angular app, it reloads the page but also generates the following error in console:

> [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

I'm calling validateAuthToken from run method of app controller which internally calls location.reload() method.

```js
.run(function ($rootScope, $urlRouter, security, $location) {
 
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e) {
    security.validateAuthToken();  
  });
});
```

```js
angular.module('security', [])

.factory('security', [ '$http', '$q', '$location', function($http, $q, $location) {

  var service = {
  validateAuthToken: function() {
      var request = $http.post(url, params);
      return request.then(
        function(response) {
          if(CONDITION_MEETS) {
           location.reload();
          }
        },
        function(error) {
        });
  }
  return service;
 }]);
```

Complete error trace:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14263)
at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14488)
at done (angular.js:9646)
at completeRequest (angular.js:9836)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestError (angular.js:9787)
```

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14381445/865175): "The error you mentioned normally occurs when you create a loop of changes over a property. For example, like when you watch for changes on a certain property and then change the value of that property on the listener"

Comment: Please post more code, so we can se whats going on. Like where you call reload() and how your controller initializes. Maybe even a running example.

Comment: Maybe you set a watch on `window` and by calling the `reload()` method on it's `location` property inside the watch callback it gets in a loop.

Comment: Added complete code scenario.

Comment: When digest cycle limit is reached the error code i believe also highlights the culprit code. Do you get any such details?

Comment: Added complete error trace, all errors are pointing to angular.js file.

Comment: What is `$locationChangeSuccess`? Reads like "on location change -> change location -> on location change -> change location ..."

Answer (score 0):

Because your code here:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e) {
    security.validateAuthToken();  
});
```

The function `validateAuthToken` will reload the page when the `$http.post` fails:

```
function(response) {
    location.reload();
},
```

Reloading the page triggers another new event `$locationChangeSuccess`, which will call `$http.post` again... So come the infinite loop. You'd better just popup a modal saying the initialization is failed, instead of reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks Joy for pointing this out. I missed some lines of code in question. location.reload() is not getting called always, only when some condition meets. Once validateAuthToken method called, location.reload() will not be called again.

Comment: Em. Then you probably need to show more code, especially the condition on which you call `reload`. Your error seems there is some infinite digest cycle.