# $rootScope:infdig 10 $digest() iterations reached MdDataTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

I'm using MdDataTable and I want to insert some html tag into `mdt-cell`. So I used `html-content="true"`:

```
<mdt-cell html-content="true"><span class="btn btn-success">button</span></mdt-cell>
```

But I get this error:

```
[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate , check this out , maybe this helps you

Comment: uhm, they say to edit the model in the controller and not in the view, but I have to simply add html content inside mdt-cell and prevent it to be overwrited

Comment: This error is always given when there is infinite recursion in ur code i think.

Comment: I think it is a bug of the component... is there a way to prevent it?