# Why I get error when I call function in controller from template?

Tags: angularjs

I try to call $http function in my controller from my template.

Here is template:

```
   <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>
         <span>Posted {{list.getDamageEvents(soData.damagesId)}}</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Here function in controller:

```
self.getDamageEvents = function (reviewsId) {
    var result;
    $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/DamageEvent/GetEventsByReviewsId/" + reviewsId).then(function (result) {
        result = result.data;
    });
    return result;
}
```

And here the error I get in browser:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Any idea why I get error above and how to fix it?

Comment: You may want to look at: [Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate)

Answer (score 0):

Can u call this method from controller and save result into $scope?

And then use this $scope variable in template?