# Increment value of scope counter by 1 gives 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting error message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to work with angularjs [and given is the JSFiddle for what I am trying to do](https://jsfiddle.net/0mscf54h/1/)

```
<div id="page-main-body">
  <div id="container" ng-repeat="hero in heroModel">
    <div id="page-header" ng-if="heroCounter === 1">
      I am header
    </div>

    <div id="page-body">
      <p>Name: {{ hero.Name }}</p>
      <p>Super hero identity: {{ hero.SuperHeroName }}</p>
    </div>

    <div id="page-footer" ng-if="heroCounter === 2">
      I am footer
    </div>
    {{ incrementHeroCounter() }} {{ resetHeroCounter() }}
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is if my model contains 4 elements it works fine, but if i remove one element from the model I don't see the footer div and I get an error message in the console which says

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:

So I think this is because I am updating the $scope variable and based on the variable value i am drawing my header and footer.

Everything works fine if my data model contains 4 or 6 elements but if i change the element count from an even count (2,4) to an odd count (1,3) I get the `$digest` error

I also read the [angular documentation for this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) but it seems like my model too remains the same and nothing changes, only variable which changes is the $scope variable of counter here and I know that may cause a change in the digest cycle but how do i cache it or use a different technique to achieve what i am trying to do here

I tried couple of previous [stack links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate) but was unable to get a good direction from it, I am not sure if for a simple thing like this i should use `service` or a `$rootScope` maybe there's a better way of doing this.

Given below is how my code looks like you may also [look at the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mscf54h/1/) and let me know what i am doing wrong here

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.heroCounter = 1;

  $scope.incrementHeroCounter = function() {
    $scope.heroCounter++;
  };

  $scope.resetHeroCounter = function() {
    if ($scope.heroCounter === 3) {
      $scope.heroCounter = 1;
    }
  };

  $scope.heroModel = [
    {
      SuperHeroName: "Superman",
      Name: "Clark kent"
    },
    {
      SuperHeroName: "Batman",
      Name: "Bruce Wyane"
    },
    {
      SuperHeroName: "Iron man",
      Name: "Tony Stark"
    },
    {
      SuperHeroName: "Shazam",
      Name: "Billy Batson"
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: @georgeawg in the html i want to print the header and then 2 div elements with data and then the footer, the third and fourth item should be printed with their own header and footer. It’s what you see in the fiddle output with 4 data elements i am trying to create a output just like that but when i change the data element count to 3 or 1 i get strange behavior. So i am looking to know if there’s a better way of doing this or how do i correct what i have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to print the header and then 2 div elements with data and then the footer, the third and fourth item should be printed with their own header and footer.

Use the `$index` special property:

```
<div id="page-main-body">
  <div id="container" ng-repeat="hero in heroModel">
    <div id="page-header" ng-hide="$index === 1">
      I am header
    </div>

    <div id="page-body">
      <p>Name: {{ hero.Name }}</p>
      <p>Super hero identity: {{ hero.SuperHeroName }}</p>
    </div>

    <div id="page-footer" ng-hide="$index === 0">
      I am footer
    </div>
    ̶{̶{̶ ̶i̶n̶c̶r̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶H̶e̶r̶o̶C̶o̶u̶n̶t̶e̶r̶(̶)̶ ̶}̶}̶ ̶{̶{̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶e̶t̶H̶e̶r̶o̶C̶o̶u̶n̶t̶e̶r̶(̶)̶ ̶}̶}̶
  </div>
</div>
```

The `$index` special property is exposed on the local scope of each `ng-repeat` template instance. It is a number iterator offset of the repeated element `(0..length-1)`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Overview](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)

Comment: I did not use $index but ended up using $odd and $even from the document you shared, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$index` property instead of your own counter. This special property is exposed on the local scope of each ng-repeat template instance. It is a number iterator offset against the repeated element.